# Selecting the most recent activity

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Im trying to get the latest lab result of the patient before his surgery and after; we want to get his hemoglobin....

Lab table would show his lab results
Problem_list_cn would show his sugery

/*this example is just for before*/

```
SELECT L.RESULT_DE 
FROM LAB L INNER JOIN PROBLEM_LIST_CN PL
ON L.PATID_CD = PL.PAT_ID 
WHERE L.PROCEDURE_DE = 'HEMOGLOBIN' 
AND L.COLLECTION_DT = (SELECT (MAX L.COLLECTION_DT) FROM LAB L2 WHERE L2.COLLECTION_DT < PL.NOTED_DATE) As HEMOG_BEFORE;
```

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: what are you getting instead of your desired outcome?

Comment: You should investigate the `LAG()` and `LEAD()` analytic functions.

Comment: It's really hard to understand your needed result without knowing the data in your tables. Please post same sample data ( formatted text) to better explain the reason of the result you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any sample data, its difficult to test, but something like this:

```
SELECT L.PATID_CD,
       MAX( L.RESULT_DE )
         KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CASE WHEN L.COLLECTION_DT < PL.NOTED_DATE
                                              THEN L.COLLECTION_DT END NULLS FIRST )
         AS HEMOG_BEFORE,
       MAX( CASE WHEN L.COLLECTION_DT < PL.NOTED_DATE THEN L.COLLECTION_DT END )
         AS DATE_TAKEN_BEFORE,
       MAX( L.RESULT_DE )
         KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN L.COLLECTION_DT >= PL.NOTED_DATE
                                               THEN L.COLLECTION_DT END NULLS LAST)
         AS HEMOG_AFTER,
       MIN( CASE WHEN L.COLLECTION_DT >= PL.NOTED_DATE THEN L.COLLECTION_DT END )
         AS DATE_TAKEN_AFTER
FROM   LAB L
       INNER JOIN PROBLEM_LIST_CN PL
       ON ( L.PATID_CD = PL.PAT_ID )
WHERE L.PROCEDURE_DE = 'HEMOGLOBIN'
GROUP BY L.PATID_CD;
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY platin_cd ORDER BY date_after ) AS rid
  FROM   (
    SELECT l.platin_cd,
           LAG( l.result_de     ) OVER ( PARTITION BY l.platin_cd
                                         ORDER BY collection_dt ) AS hemog_before,
           LAG( l.collection_dt ) OVER ( PARTITION BY l.platin_cd
                                         ORDER BY collection_dt ) AS date_before,
           l.result_de AS hemog_after,
           l.collection_dt AS date_after,
           pl.noted_date
    FROM   LAB L
           INNER JOIN PROBLEM_LIST_CN PL
           ON ( L.PATID_CD = PL.PAT_ID )
    WHERE L.PROCEDURE_DE = 'HEMOGLOBIN'
  )
  WHERE  date_after >= noted_date
)
WHERE  rid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the field LAB.PATID_CD contains the id of the patient, you should change your query as follows (i.e. joining the subquery on PATID_CD too). I added a small correction on the MAX function parenthesys too.

```
   SELECT L.RESULT_DE 
   FROM LAB L INNER JOIN PROBLEM_LIST_CN PL
    ON L.PATID_CD = PL.PAT_ID 
   WHERE L.PROCEDURE_DE = 'HEMOGLOBIN' 
   AND L.COLLECTION_DT = (SELECT (MAX (L.COLLECTION_DT) FROM LAB L2 WHERE L2.COLLECTION_DT < PL.NOTED_DATE AND L2.PATID_CD=l.PATID_CD) As HEMOG_BEFORE;
```